# QGIS sensor data through API

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a bunch of sensors at fixed locations. I want to push this data into QGIS through an API. I am not able to find a way to push data through API.

Looking for some help or examples preferably in Python.

Comment: Will the sensors "push" the data to Qgis?

Comment: Thats what I thought. As we have data streaming in from the Sensors, I thought I can just push that data into QGIS.

Comment: Can you give more details about your data and sensors?  Have you read this https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: Sensors capture information like Temperature, Humidity. It then sends the data using MQTT protocol to a central broker. I can make the sensors do HTTP/HTTPS push to an API, which I what I am anticipating in doing for QGIS.